# JQuery trigger a button click once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a jQuery function that creates seven input fields when a button is clicked. This should be allowed only once, and not every time the button is pressed.

At the moment I have the below code that creates one text field, but the problem is that every time the button is pressed more text fields are added. By creating these text fields I can use them to add records in my database. For example by clicking the `addbutton`, the text fields will be created and the user could enter the information.

```
$("#addbutton").bind("click", function() { 
    var textarea = $('<input type="text" name="firstname">',);
    $('#textfields').append(textarea);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Okay, so what's your question?

Comment: Let's clarify: button is clicked, seven input fields are created, clicking again on the button does not create any more input fields. Right?

Comment: Checkout the `.one` method for only allowing one click.

Comment: @AGE Clicking again on the button does create addition input fields, and I don't want this.

Comment: @bto.rdz Let's suppose I create the input fields, and then I submit the data with another button, what happens if I want to click again to enter new information?

Comment: Why did everybody mark down my question? It wasn't a legitimate question?

Comment: @Otonel could be due to your question needed to be clarified, I edited the statement to be more relevant and easier to understand

Comment: @Otonel mine wasnt rewarded best anwser? Wow, i explained you three facts above what you wanted.

Comment: @ewrwr I tried his answer first and worked for me.sorry

Comment: Oh no problem i thought i had  a misunderstanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fire the event handler only once with `one()`, and just append the buttons you want, I'm using an array of names and `$.map` to create them

```
$("#addbutton").one("click", function() {

     var buttons = [
         'firstname',
         'lastname',
         ..... etc
     ];

     $('#textfields').append(
         $.map(buttons, function(_name) {
             return $('<input />', { name : _name })
         })
     );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7204ssmd/)

Comment: How can I identify each text field so I can get the data from them?

Comment: Target them by the name you've given them

Answer (score 1):

According to our chat in your comments, you want a button that:

1. On click, it creates *seven* input fields and appends them to your `#textfields` element.
2. After the fields are created, the button is not allowed to create any more input fields.

I devised the following solution based upon this interpretation:

```js
$("#addbutton").click(function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 7; ++i){
    $('#textfields').append('<input type="text" name="firstname">');
  }
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addbutton">Click Me</button>
<div id="textfields"></div>
```

Long story short, the button is disabled after the first click. This prevents you or anyone from doing anything else with the button.

Alternatively you could create a global variable which will act as a flag, to help prevent further input fields from being created, by wrapping the input creation code with an if statement like so:
    var inputFieldsCreated = false;

```
$("#addbutton").click(function(){
  if(inputFieldsCreated === false){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < 7; ++i){
      $('#textfields').append('<input type="text" name="firstname">');
    }
    inputFieldsCreated = true;
  }
});
```

Let me know if this does the job for you in the comments below.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I don't like using JQuery for such easy/simple/short thing, here's the code with pure JavaScript :

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", onClick, false);

function onClick() {
    var textfield, br;
    for(var i=0 ; i<7 ; i++) {
        textfield = document.createElement("input");
        br = document.createElement("br");
        textfield.id = "txt_"+i;
        document.getElementById("textFields").appendChild(textfield);
        document.getElementById("textFields").appendChild(br);
    }
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
```

cou can test it here :
https://jsfiddle.net/v91v7afa/

Of course, instead of deleting the button, you can `disable` it, but it would be really easy to re-enable it. Or you can [remove the listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

```
var numText=1;
$("#addbutton").on("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      numText++;
      $('#textfields').append('<input type="text" name="firstname" />');
      if (numText==7)
          $(this).off('click')

});
```

Comment: Read the question again.